# TypeScript: Check if derived class implements method

Tags: reflection, typescript

I got two classes, one deriving from the other, and on the base class I need to check if the derived class is implementing a method with a specific name:

```
class Foo {
    constructor() { }

    childHasMethod() {
        if(this.method) {
            console.log('Yay');
        } else {
            console.log('Nay');
        }
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.childHasMethod();
    }

    method() {

    }
}

var bar = new Bar();
```

Even though the line `if(this.method) {` is marked red on the playground, it works. But the local compiler throws a compilation error: `The property 'method' does not exist on value of type 'Foo'`.

Is there a clean way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to "sneak it past the compiler" you can treat `this` as dynamic:

```
(<any>this).method
```

I have made a full example of this on the [TypeScript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=class%20Foo%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20constructor%28%29%20%7B%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20childHasMethod%28%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%28%28%3Cany%3Ethis%29.method%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20alert%28%27Yay%27%29;%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20alert%28%27Nay%27%29;%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20Bar%20extends%20Foo%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20constructor%28%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super%28%29;%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.childHasMethod%28%29;%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20method%28%29%20%7B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20Baz%20extends%20Foo%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20constructor%28%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super%28%29;%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.childHasMethod%28%29;%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%7D%0A%0Avar%20bar%20=%20new%20Bar%28%29;%0Avar%20baz%20=%20new%20Baz%28%29;).

```
childHasMethod() {
    if((<any>this).method) {
        alert('Yay');
    } else {
        alert('Nay');
    }
}
```

Having said this, having a base class know details about its sub-classes could get you into tricky places. Usually I would try to avoid this as it sounds like the specialisations are leaking into the base class - but you may have a particular thing you are doing and know your program better than me so I'm not saying "don't do this" - just "are you sure" :)

Comment: I will of course try to avoid it, but there are frameworks which make heavy use of those "reflection"-stuff, and I was sure there needs to be a way to do this.
Thanks for your fast and perfect answer!